# Model fields not being displayed in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

actually I am beginner learning django and i wanted to create my own project. so i started with making models and fields of all required apps then i also registered in `admin.py` but still the fields are not being shown in the django admin panel.

So this is `models.py` of one of my django app.

```
from django.db import models
from authentication.models import User
from course_management.models import Course
# Create your models here.
class Attendance(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course=models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date=models.DateField()
    status=models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

and I have registered it in `admin.py` as well, but still the fields are not shown in django admin. this is happening with all the other django apps as well.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Attendance
# Register your models here.
class AttendanceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('user','course','date','status')
admin.site.register(Attendance,AttendanceAdmin)
```

Comment: Try commenting out your code in admin.py. Does other apps appear in admin web page?

Comment: Did you run makemigrations and migrate?

Comment: @Pycm yes i did make the initial migrations

Comment: Can you post what you see in admin page?

Comment: You have to run migrations after creation of every db mode. Not just initial at project creation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think you did not register your app in installed_apps of settings file

Comment: @AliShekari i have done that

Comment: @pycm ohh thank you so muchhhh i forgot abt it.thankyouuuu

Answer (score 0):

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```